# source destination table without duplication

Tags: sql

i m trying to create a new data table using the table below :

```
ID City        Language
1  Paris       French 
2  New York    English
3  Delhi       English
4  Berlin      German
5  Marseille   French
6  Hamburg     German
```

the ouput should be something like this:

```
City 1 City2       Language
Paris  Marseille   French
NY     Delhi       English
Berlin Hamburg     German
```

the main idea here is to avoid 2 rows with same city like for example Paris-Marseille and Marseille-Paris.
please advise on how to achieve it.

Comment: What if there are more than two cities for a given language?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select min(city), max(city), language
from t
group by language;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The table have indeed tousand of entries. The purpose is to have a source X, destination Y without having source Y, destination X in the table.

Comment: @nouamanefloyd . . . This meets that requirement and should work on the sample data from your question.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two rows per language, then simple aggregation is enough:

```
select min(city) city1, max(city) city2, language
from mytable
group by language
```

If you want to possibly handle more cities, and/or control the order in which they appear in the columns based on the `id` of the intial row, then you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(case when rn = 1 then city end) city1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then city end) city2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then city end) city3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by language order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by language
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The table have indeed tousand of entries. The purpose is to have a source X, destination Y without having source Y, destination X in the table.